# Poltergeist - turning off JQMIGRATE warnings

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, poltergeist

When running my test suite using poltergeist as the JavaScript driver, I am encountering the following warnings:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.attr(selected) may use property instead of attribute
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated
```

Is that possible to turn them off?

Answer (score 31):

Look for `jQuery.migrateMute = false` in `jquery-migrate.js` and set it to `true`

Comment: Can't you set it from outside the file, so that your changes don't get overridden when upgrading, etc?

Comment: Alternatively you can indeed just set it to true in your own scripts (outside of migrate script). Tested it on my own project and it works.

Answer (score 31):

Minified version is "muted" by default:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not true. I am using https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.4.1.min.js and i see warning in console. I downloaded not minified, muted and reminified

Answer (score 4):

Following the answer from benchwarmer, this:

```
function custom_mute_jquery_migrator() {   
    echo '<script>jQuery.migrateMute = true;</script>';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_mute_jquery_migrator' );
add_action( 'admin_head', 'custom_mute_jquery_migrator' );
```

Fixed it for me.
Thanks @benchwarmer.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve that problem (temporarily) by adding to functions.php:

```
    function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    .jquery-migrate-deprecation-notice{
    display: none !important;
}
    } 
  </style>';
}
```

and it works!

Answer (score -1):

There is a newer minified version available.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: mind that version 3.x is for migrating to jQuery v3+ only and cannot be used in that case!